# Difference between “combination of ” and “combination between”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

I have read both two uses:

1. The *combinations of* a, b and c, taken two at a time, are ab, bc, ac.
2. We can not help but noticing a harmonious *combination between* classic and contemporary.

Are both uses interchangeable? Perhaps substitute *combinations among* for *combinations of* in the first sentence? Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When two or more things are combined, it is a ***combination of*** them. You cannot have a combination 'between' or 'among.' 'Of' is the correct preposition to use.

Comment: Thank you Tony. Do you mean that only _combination of_ is right. So the expressions of _combination between_ and _combination among_ are incorrect.

Comment: @macio.Jun Yes, that is my position. 'Between' and 'among' are incorrect and I don't believe there are any circumstances where a preposition other than 'of' is possible or acceptable.

Answer (score 5):

What Tony said. Here's the [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combination+of%2C+combination+between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)
[image]